# Portable Googleless Chromium web browser to use for testing

Tags: web-browser, web, portable, chromium, webrtc

Please recommend a web browser with the following requirements:

1. Windows 7-10 compatible.
2. Completely portable.  Absolutely no registry writes or writing files outside of its own dedicated folder(s)/subfolder(s).
3. No tracking or analytics (or easy to completely disable ***before*** the browser is run).
4. Uses the Chromium web rendering engine.
5. Frequently updated with the latest Chromium engine (especially when Chromium has a security issue).
6. Includes WebRTC functionality.
7. No contact with any endpoints (such as Google or Microsoft) except the ones actually required to establish user-requested connections.  An exception can be made if it downloads Google's Safe Browsing list or something similar (but hopefully this can be disabled).

Optional: Support extensions/add-ons.

My goal is to use this for testing, including testing WebRTC.

I thought [Ungoogled Chromium](https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium) would do the job, but the Windows version does not appear to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

[Ungoogled Chromium from Portapps](https://github.com/portapps/ungoogled-chromium-portable): This adds the portable feature, which is the only missing item in Ungoogled Chromium. The best solution for you if you just want Chromium without Google.

[Iridium Browser](https://iridiumbrowser.de): An another Chromium browser. In fact, this is quite similar to Ungoogled Chromium and it meets all the requirements. As an extra, it's also privacy-focused and enforces for some security protocols.

Comment: Thank you Ismail.  Can you update your answer to indicate if each of those recommendations meets the requirements stated in the question?  Also, can you include links in your answer?  Is one of the options you presented a better match than the other?  Thanks!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket You are right. I made several improvements.

Comment: Thank you Ismail!  Iridium looks like it could work perfectly.  I remember hearing a lot about Iridium several years ago, and then I haven't heard anything recently.  Are there any big issues preventing it from being more popular?

Comment: For a while, I used it for the Selenium driver. I had no problems with Iridium but I switched to Ungoogled because it is more "native" I guess. If I had to choose one; I could choose Iridium for browsing and Ungoogled for testing. But you want extension support, I didn't see it when I first read it. You can use Iridium because Ungoogled can't download extensions from Web Store.